# Probability birthday as me

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to find some help on a text book question which I cannot solve by my own.

This is from the while loop chapter. so I have to use while loop to get the answer

the answer is something like
"With 253 students, the prob is greater than 50% that someone has the same birthday as you."

we have to get "253" and "50%" by using while loop
I created

```
classmate = 1
prob = 0
while prob <= 50:
    classmate = classmate + 1
    prob = (364 / 365) ** classmate
print('With {} student, the probability is greater than {} that someone '
      'has the same birthday as you.'.format(classmate, prob))
```

However, it does not show any result. What should I go?

P.S. this is the "while" chapter, so I only allow to use while to get the answer.....

Comment: What is the objective of this? It goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this approach. First, you should test for a probability threshold of 0.50, not 50 -- all probabilities are between 0.0 and 1.0.  Second, your current formula for `prob` is the probability of no matching birthday, not a matching birthday -- change this to 1 minus your current formula. Lastly, if this is in Python 2, `364/365` equals 0 (integer math) -- try `364.0/365.0` instead.

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed - go to http://math.stackexchange.com and request an explanation. You can also look there: mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.birthdayprob.html

Comment: @ReblochonMasque be careful confusing the birthday paradox (any 2 people) with sharing the birthday with someone specific, e.g. "you". This problem just boils down to given a specific number, how many times do you have to role a 365 sided dice to get the same number with `>50%` chance.

Comment: You are correct AChampion, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the calculation of `prob`.

1. Probabilities are usually measured between 0 and 1.
2. The probability that someone doesn't have your birthday is `364/365` (or `364.0/365` in Py2 to avoid integer division issues)
3. You should start with `0` classmates

Your logic corrected:

```
In []:
classmate = 0
prob = 1
while prob >= 0.50:
    classmate += 1
    prob *= (364 / 365)   # Py 2 (364.0/365)
print('With {} student, the probability is greater than {:.0%} that someone '
      'has the same birthday as you.'.format(classmate, 1-prob))

Out []:
With 253 student, the probability is greater than 50% that someone has the same birthday as you.
```

Comment: The answer is wrong... from memory, the number of students is closer to 23. It is a problem with the reasoning of the OP, not a programming mishap.
http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.birthdayprob.html

Comment: @ReblochonMasque you are mistaken that is the chance any 2 people have the same birthday... not that they have the same birthday as you!

Comment: That should be even less students then...

Comment: Why? The chance of any 2 students having the same birthday is much higher than the chance that they have the same birthday as "you".

Comment: Yes, in consequence, you need a smaller group for this to happen, don't you?

Comment: You need a much smaller group (`23`) to have any 2 people to have the same birthday - you need much bigger group to have the same birthday as you (`253`) - with `>50%` probability.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, sorry, I am really thick and slow this morning! Thank you!

Comment: I found out the reason of getting no result is if I do in my way, the prob after 253 will decrease, so it will lead to infinite loop. and Thank you BTW

Comment: `(364/365)**n` is a decreasing number as `n` increases (and always below `1`). Doing `prob = (364/365)**n` is more expensive than doing `prob *= 364/365` (same result).